# Drawing stippled lines using OpenGL

Tags: opengl

When drawing stippled line with OpenGL, the result appears to be very strange. The straight line seems fine.But the curved line is broken. The curved line is the outline of a polygon with hundreds of vertex.

I tried to change the line width and turn on the smooth option. All show the same results. Anyone knows where the problem is?

```
info.lineStye = 0xE0E0
```

[image]

Codes rendering the polyline is listed below, `info` stores the line data

```
    glColor3ub(info.R, info.G, info.B);
    glLineWidth(info.lnWidth);
    glLineStipple(1, info.lineStyle);
    glEnable( GL_LINE_STIPPLE );

    if (info.bSmooth)
    {
        glEnable( GL_LINE_SMOOTH );
        glHint( GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST );
        glEnable( GL_BLEND );
        glBlendFunc( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );
    }
    else
    {
        glDisable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
        glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    }

    glVertexPointer(2,GL_SHORT,0,(void*)vertOfst);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, info.nPts);
```

Comment: I suspect your GL_LINES don't connect right, causing stipple pattern to restart. Try drawing a GL_LINE_STRIP instead.

Comment: @Andreas That's correct! Thanks. How could I promote comments to accepted answer?

Comment: Great! You can't promote comments as answers. I took the liberty of making an answer quoting my own comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting my own comment:

> I suspect your GL_LINES don't connect right, causing stipple pattern
>   to restart. Try drawing a GL_LINE_STRIP instead.